# OpenGL Displaying Two Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, polygon

I'm needing some help with some c++/OpenGL coding. What I'm doing is a polygon approximation algorithm.

My code first pulls in a set of points from a .txt file, stores them all in an array and then displays that array. It then takes those points and performs the algorithm on them, and creates a new array of points. What I can't figure out how to do, is how to get that second set of points displayed on the same window as the first. Do I have to create a new display function and call that one? Or maybe modify the basic display function that I have now to accept an array? Here's the code for my display function:

```
void display(void){
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1,1,1);

    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for(int i=0; i<2000; i++)
        glVertex2i(pixel[i].x,pixel[i].y);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to draw the processed array. Considering that you just want to render the resulting points, like in your code sample, you could use:

```
void display(void){
  glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor3f(1,1,1);

  glBegin(GL_POINTS);
  for(int i=0; i<2000; i++)
    glVertex2i(pixel[i].x,pixel[i].y);
  // here goes the rendering of the new set of points.
  glColor3f(1,0,0); // change the color so we can see better the new points.
  for(int i=0; i<2000; i++)
    glVertex2i(result[i].x,result[i].y);
  glEnd();

  glFlush();
}
```

The variable `result` is your array with the results of the processing.

You can not modify the `display` function since it is called by the OpenGL and it does not know about your arrays. But nothing goes against you splitting your code into many functions called by your `display` function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That works. So by using the above, I'd have to render them both at the same time. So I'd call glutMainLoop() after the algorithm was completed instead of before?

Comment: If I understood correctly what you meant, glutMainLoop() is always called before the display function. When you call glutMainLoop, the rendering loop starts (each iteration renders exactly one frame). The display functions is called in every iteration and is responsible for rendering the frame. That's why you must call glutDisplayFunc in your code before calling glutMainLoop: so you specify to the GLUT which function will do the rendering.